# What would this have to do with a courtroom?

Tags: riddle

> "When I'm at home, you might put me up.
>   When I'm not, someone puts you up.
>
> ---
>
> What am I?"

Comment: It does sound kind of vague with multiple possible answers, especially the second line, which makes this riddle contain a total of 3 factors, "me", "you" and "they". Boy I hope this has satisfying answer!

Comment: I hope I don't leave you frustrated.  I didn't really consider how many different countries are represented here.  Thus, a riddle that depends on American idiom might *not* make sense to someone from India.  I hope that doesn't raise anyone's bp!  8-)

Comment: Relax, I am familiar with most American idioms, and I don't get my bp up that easily. :)

Comment: Heh.  A lot of folks sure got their bp up over my first attempt.  I even told them in the *title* that it was "Not that stupid -gry puzzle," and some commenters *still* got angry that the answer did not "end in 'gry.'"

Comment: Anyways, I'll make my guess, although it doesn't involve any idioms so I'm doubtful.

Comment: With regards to the _quality standards_, it stems from the Stack Overflow Q&A format. The bot assumes if you haven't written many words, your question might be considered low-quality (i.e. a single sentence).

Comment: You ought to consider giving your posts more descriptive titles. Seeing something labeled "What Am I? # X" does not really inspire folks to click through, plus it's hard to remember which one it is if you're looking for it later on.

Comment: @feelinferrety I'm certainly open to suggestions.  Please help me out. What might you have called this one, as an example? (I thought about looking for a category or something related to what I was looking for in the answer, and decided maybe the title should not contain a hint.  People got so hacked off over "Not that stupid -gry puzzle," and **that** one had a really clear hint in the title.)

Comment: Usually something to do with the riddle itself, or a related pun/play-on-words. Often, people will use the title as a sort of confirmation for a correct answer (i.e. It seems random or unrelated at first, but after doing the line-by-line analysis, it suddenly becomes clear what the association is). For this one, I might title it something like "Why do I put up with you?"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about:

> **A suitcase?**

*When I'm at home, you might put me up.*

> When it's at home, you might put it up (that is, store it away).

*When I'm not, someone puts you up.*

> When it's not, it's with you and someone puts *you* up (that is, gives you a place to stay).

*What would this have to do with a courtroom?*

> Both a suit *and* a case relate to courtrooms.

[BTW, I was writing the answer below when Lee Leon's answer popped up and I discarded mine, thinking theirs was much better. It still seems too farfetched (certainly now with the clue in the title), but I'll attach it too anyway:]

> It was **'a tent'** with the reasoning that when a tent is 'at home' (outdoors) you put it up (erect it), and when it's not, it's because you sought lodgings instead.

Comment: You are correct!  Did the title make it too easy?  I was advised (by a moderator, I think) that I should put a title on my riddles.  Before that, I was just numbering them by type. Please let me know if you feel the title made it too easy.  I'm trying to find that sweet spot of keeping the moderators happy, but also making good puzzles.

Comment: Believe it or not, but I didn't spot the new title... I only saw it *after* posting, thought for a second that I answered the wrong question <facepalm>, then realized what happened and quickly added that part in an edit. So I wouldn't know. ;) But this was posted a full 10 hours after the title change, so maybe not? Anyway, cool riddle :)

Answer (score 3):

Is it

> A camp bed?

When at home

> You might put it up for guests

When not at home

> Your host(s) use it to put you up - meaning they give you a bed for the night.

Comment: This is very close.  You have part of it, too.

Answer (score 2):

At the risk of being obvious:

> feet?

When I'm at home, you might put me up.

> As a form of relaxation, people put their feet up. I think this is probably more of an idiom than what people do nowadays though.

When I'm not, they put you up

> If you're not at home, you might be out walking or on your feet in some other regard, and therefore your feet put you up-*right*. Doesn't really apply for all reasons for leaving the house, but many.

Comment: Ah I think you've gotten it.

Comment: No, sorry. While the "I" is not really something that would speak (and so it seems strange to think of it as "an individual"), the "I, you, & they" are all distinct. So the "I" you might put up does not switch to a "they" later on.

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> Curtains?

When I'm at home, you might put me up.

> Curtains inside a home are put up by the home owner

When I'm not, they put you up.

> Outside the home (e.g. theatre), "they" put curtains up to signal the start of a show.

Yes, I am aware the specific wordplay and pronouns involved do not make sense, but I wanted to guess nevertheless :)

Comment: It's a nice try.  It nearly fits, but you're correct; it doesn't quite match the pronouns. Does it help if I tell you that "put x up" ends up meaning two quite distinct things?

Answer (score 0):

Might be a stretch, but how about a

> Bunk bed ladder?

When I'm at home you might put me up

> When you have a bunk bed ladder at home, a child can put the ladder up against the bed and use it to get up.

When I'm not at home they might put you up

> If there isn't a bunk bed ladder at home, the parents may have to put the child up into the bed.

Comment: I have to admit, this kind of fits, although I don't know about the bunk bed ladder not being home.  Where would it go?  8-). Still, +1 for a creative solution!

Answer (score 0):

I guess, it is

> SILENCE

As,

"When I'm at home, you might put me up.

> Once in home, you usually need not be maintaining the needed 'slience'

When I'm not, someone puts you up.

> When it is not silent (means if it is too noisy in one's home), neighbours may complain against you (can translate to 'put you up' colloquially!)

And its link with the title is

> Silence is the main requirement in a courtroom (while court proceedings are on)

Comment: Huh.  This is a colloquialism I have never heard.  So  >! "He put me up"   would mean "He reported me to the authorities?"  If so . . . well, I think that fits as well as the intended answer, even though that is **not** the answer I built the riddle around.  I have no clear idea how to handle this.  It isn't **right,** exactly, but it isn't **wrong,** either.  I'm pretty new here.  Do I mark this solved, or not?  I would say "no," but I want to give credit where credit is due . . . Moderators?  I think we need a ruling . . .

Comment: Hmmm. . . . Looking at it now, if I had said "Someone **might** put you up," then this answer would **also** be correct.  But since you might get reported, but you also might **not**, I'd say this answer does not **quite** fit as well as the intended answer.  If a moderator rules differently, I will bow to their experience and wisdom.  Still, a +1 for your answer, as it showed great cleverness!